# PanelGrid não divide colunas com Repeat

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um panelgrid que não consigo de forma alguma dividir em colunas um ui:repeat, seja a quantidade que for.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" >

    <ui:repeat var="p" value="#{cadSetor.campos}" >

        <p:commandLink  actionListener="#{telaLogin.chamaTelaSelecao(p.id)}" ajax="false">
            <p:graphicImage value="/imagensSetores/#{p.nomeImagem}" width="210" style="border: 0px; margin-top:1px" />
        </p:commandLink>

    </ui:repeat>

</h:panelGrid>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Não consegui entender sua dúvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ui: repeat` não vai funcionar porque ele realmente não adiciona componentes a árvore de componentes.

`ui: repeat` funciona apenas durante a fase de renderização e renderiza novamente seus componentes filhos várias vezes com o estado diferente.

Alguns componentes, como `panelGrid`, mas também tabela de dados, esperam ter algumas crianças na árvore de componentes, a fim de funcionar corretamente. Desde que `ui: repeat` não adiciona eles,essa abordagem não funciona.

Tente utilizar `c:foreach` pois pode ser uma solução no lugar do `ui: repeat`.

Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat) sobre `c:foreach` para melhor entendimento do por que para esta questão,`c:foreach` pode ser melhor.

Comment: Novatec, tive um problema posterior ao uso do c:foreach, algumas vezes simplesmente, os objetos não são criados na tela, quando pressiono F5, ai funciona, é como se o c:foreach não conseguisse ler a minha lista:

<c:forEach var="p" items="#{cadSetor.listaSetores}">
Se souber o que pode ser, agradeço.